# Stacks of Chocolate

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a mathematical problem about building a gigantic gift package of Finnish chocolate. The goal is to include same amount of each brand in the package. However, the bar sizes between the brands differ ( Goodio 48g, Chjoko 80g, Panda 145g, Brunberg 150g, Fazer 200g ). How do I determine the amount of packages I need to buy from each brand to get the total amount of chocolate from each brand to be equal?

Comment: Are you familiar with the idea of [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple)?

Comment: For what it's worth, this is a Number Theory problem rather than a Calculus problem.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming these five brands only come in sizes of 48, 80, 145, 150, and 200, what we essentially want to find is the least common multiple of all these numbers, denoted $\text{lcm}(48, 80, 145, 150, 200)$. You won't like the answer, but in this case it turns out to be 34,800, meaning you would have to buy:
\begin{align}
725 &\text{ Goodio}\\
435 &\text{ Chjoko}\\
240 &\text{ Panda}\\
232 &\text{ Brunberg}\\
174 &\text{ Fazer}.
\end{align}

Comment: If you like chocolate, you may actually like this answer...

Answer (score 3):

The lcm gives the exact solution, but in practice you are probably more interested by an approximative solution.

I listed below the packages in decreasing order that would minimize $\displaystyle\min_{r\in\{G,C,P,B,F\}}\sum\limits_{i\in\{G,C,P,B,F\}}|n_r\,w_r-n_i\,w_i|$, where $w_i$ are the weight of each brand and $n_i$ the number of items of that brand.

$\begin{array}{|rrrrr|rrrrr|r|}\hline
n_G&n_C&n_P&n_B&n_F &M_G&M_C&M_P&M_B&M_F&\text{diff}\\\hline
1   &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &    48 &    80 &     0 &     0 &     0 & 176\\
3   &   2 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   144 &   160 &   145 &   150 &   200 & 76\\
3   &   2 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   144 &   160 &   145 &   150 &   200 & 71\\
12  &   7 &   4 &   4 &   3 &   576 &   560 &   580 &   600 &   600 & 64\\
25  &  15 &   8 &   8 &   6 &  1200 &  1200 &  1160 &  1200 &  1200 & 40\\
75  &  45 &  25 &  24 &  18 &  3600 &  3600 &  3625 &  3600 &  3600 & 25\\
100 &  60 &  33 &  32 &  24 &  4800 &  4800 &  4785 &  4800 &  4800 & 15\\
175 & 105 &  58 &  56 &  42 &  8400 &  8400 &  8410 &  8400 &  8400 & 10\\
275 & 165 &  91 &  88 &  66 & 13200 & 13200 & 13195 & 13200 & 13200 & 5\\
725 & 435 & 240 & 232 & 174 & 34800 & 34800 & 34800 & 34800 & 34800 & 0\\
\hline\end{array}$

Here are the results I got, in practice having a difference of $10g$ over $8.4 kg$ for instance for the $9^{th}$ line cannot be considered so much of a fuss.

Also you may want to consider finding another packaging for Panda as it is the one that provokes most of the difference.